# Deleting a specific taxi booking that is stored in an SQLite 3 database with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am new to Python and for my first university assignment I have to make a taxi booking system, one of the features needs to be that the user can delete a previous booking.

I have managed to get the selecting and listing of the bookings working but I cannot figure out how to delete one, here is what I have so far.

```
def cancel_booking(user_id):
    print("\n")
    print("Cancel a Booking")
    with sqlite3.connect('Database.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()

    # bookings which belong to the current user
    sql = ''' SELECT * FROM booking WHERE customer_id=?'''
    cursor.execute(sql, (user_id,))
    bookings = cursor.fetchall()

    # Listing all the available bookings
    for i, b in enumerate(bookings, 1):
        print(str(i) + ") ""Number: """ + str(b[3]) + " Postcode: """ + str(b[4]),
              """ -> Number: """ + str(b[5]) + " Postcode: """ + str(b[6]))

    select_delete = input("Please select the number of the booking that you would like to delete:")
    index = int(select_delete)
    booking = bookings[index]
    bookingid = (booking[0],)

    delete_booking = """DELETE FROM booking WHERE customer_id=?"""
    cursor.execute(delete_booking, user_id)
    db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The portion where you add a booking the code where you execute the SQL has parentheses around user_id.

```
cursor.execute(sql, (user_id,))
```

but for the delete_booking code it does not.

```
 cursor.execute(delete_booking, user_id)
```

Comment: Yes you need to supply a tuple for your parameters. By adding the `(user_id,)` that is including the comma! you create a tuple of 1 value